# I can't run ngxPrint in angular

Tags: html, angular

I have a page with results. I can download this page as pdf. But I can't print where could I have done wrong?

```
<div>
<button class="btn btn-sm" printSectionId="pdf-print"
[useExistingCss]="true" ngxPrint
style="font-size:13px;">Yazdır</button>
```

print window comes up and disappears immediately.

Comment: could u share some more code so i can understand were you have went wrong

Comment: I solved the problem,

I upgraded the ngxPrint plugin to the latest version. "ngx-print": "^ 1.2.0-beta.2", version has this error.